# How to dynamically update a variable value in another function after click event in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to update the variables name `img` and `imgcaption` on event click so the `imgplay()` function will immediately get the changed values and display without page reload. The function is within a jQuery plugin which cannot be edited.

At this point when a click occurs, the value is changed within click function container but out side it returns null. How can I get the variable inside `imgplay()` to dynamically update with the new values?

**HTML**

```html
<ul id="imglist">
  <li><a href="img1.jpg">img 1<span>the image 1</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="img2.jpg">img 2<span>the image 2</span></a></li>
</ul>

<!-- display -->
<div id="gallery-container"></div>
```

**JS**

```js
$(function() {

var img, imgcaption;
$("#imglist a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  img = $(this).attr("href");
  imgcaption = $(this).find("span").text();
});

// pass updated variable to function
gallery.imgplay("#gallery-container", {
  media: {photo: img, caption: imgcaption}
},
options: {
  size: {width: "600px", height: "480px"}
});

});
```

#### Tried using localStorage

I was able to get new values via local store but I have to reload the page. It works but is not my desire.

```js
$("#imglist a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  localStorage.clear();
  localStorage.img = $(this).attr("href");
  localStorage.imgcaption = $(this).find("span").text();
  location.reload();
});

gallery.imgplay("#gallery-container", {
  media: {photo: localStorage.img, caption: localStorage.imgcaption}
}
```